# Request Entity too large error in java apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

While searching the solution for this issue, I read somewhere that max size of get request is 8Kb. However when I am trying to execute get request of content length of only 248 bytes and total URL length of only 282 characters through Apache HttpClient execute method, Apache HttpClient is giving me error: `org.apache.http.HttpException: HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large`.

However the same get request (the same URL) gives expected response in browser (and NOT "413 Request Entity Too Large").

Apache HttpClient execute method is working fine for some other get request which is slightly smaller in length and has lesser no. of query params.

I also tried sending the Post request but still got the same error.

Please help me resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated 
The other seemingly similar questions didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I would try to capture the request (wireshark) to see if you are actually sending the request with the correct size.

Comment: Here you can see that some client might limits you to 255. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: Is there any way (any method to call or override) to set or increase the maximum allowed request entity size in apache httpclient jar.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the issue was not on client side. But the internal API that I am using was sending incorrect 413 response code instead of (almost) correct response code 507.

Answer (score 0):

Request Entity too large error, comes due to server receiving request that are larger than configured to process. It should not be from the client side, you need to modify you server setting to allow larger request body length. This parameter will differ server to server.

Some of them are listed [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file)

Comment: The request is not reaching server at all. I am getting the error on client side only. The same request when sent through postman or through browser is giving correct response. However when I am sending the request through apache httpclient execute method in java, it is giving error:
`org.apache.http.HttpException: HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large`
Is there any way (any method to call or override) to set the maximum allowed request entity size in apache httpclient jar. Thanks in advance.